# Using module protractor-pageobject passing in elements to new Component

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to use this module [protractor-pageobject](https://github.com/saadtazi/protractor-pageobject). But I can't seem to figure out how to pass elements to the constructor of the Components object. The goal is to pass element selectors to a generic class for reuse. I am able to create page objects and component object without passing in parameters, but I must be missing something in the documentation when passing parameters.

my latest attempt was:

```
  comps: {
    header: require('header.co')(els.title)
  },
```

then in the generic class:

```
var Component = require('protractor-pageobject').Component;
var Header = new Component(el).extend({


els: {
  title = el
}

title: function(){
  this.element('title').getText();
}

setElements: function(){
  els.title = elements.title;
}


});

module.exports = Header;
```

Comment: Here is what the documentation says on how to pass parameters `comps: { widget: { model: 'model_file.js, opts: { key: 'value' } } } ` , but when I try this I keep getting a "you should provide an element object"